# Android Debugger - Firebase objects are obfuscated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-proguard, android-debug

I currently have an Android App that is using Firebase Auth. After google login, I get a `FirebaseUser` object. If I set a breakpoint and look at the object. I see obfuscated objects and values. See image:

[image]

Proguard is disabled for debug so I'm guessing that is not the issue:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase library files are obsuscated themselves. You cannot really do anything about it. I guess Google does not want to make everything from their libraries public due to security reasons or using the library incorrectly.